# how to compose functions that return Bool together

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to compose these functions together?

```
data Patient = Patient
  { name :: Name,
    sex :: Sex,
    age :: Int,
    height :: Int,
    weight :: Int,
    bloodType :: BloodType
  }

canDonate :: BloodType -> BloodType -> Bool

canDonateTo :: Patient -> Patient -> Bool
```

Currently I'm just manually applying them

```
canDonateTo :: Patient -> Patient -> Bool
canDonateTo x y = canDonate (bloodType x) (bloodType y)
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I like your way better than `Data.Function.on`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Data.Function.on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on):

```
import Data.Function (on)

canDonateTo = canDonate `on` bloodType
```

(Basically, your approach just inlined the definition of `on`, which could be defined as

```
on f g x y = f (g x) (g y)
```

)